# Weird text appears after re allocating memory in a struct

Tags: c

Weird characters appear after printing strings from pointer to array of pointers. Sometimes even crashes like the memory ran out. Why is that?
Every thing needs to be dynamic. Sometimes if i write only one or two reasons those bugs don't happen. output - a═══asda or adsas═²²²²²²════⌡X╩▒2.

```
#define MAX_LENGTH 50
#define ONE 1
#define TWO 2
#define THREE 3
#define EXIT 4

typedef struct list
{
    char** reasons;

}list;

int main(void)
{
    list pros = { (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_LENGTH) };
    list cons = { (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_LENGTH) };
    char* reason = 0;
    char* dillema  = 0;
    reason = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_LENGTH);
    dillema = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_LENGTH);
    printf("What is your dillema? \n");
    fgets(dillema, MAX_LENGTH, stdin);
    dillema[strcspn(dillema, "\n")] = 0;
    dillema = (char*)realloc(dillema, sizeof(char) * strlen(dillema) + ONE);

        switch (selection)
        {
        case ONE:
            printf("Enter a reason to add to list PRO: \n");
            fgets(reason, MAX_LENGTH, stdin);
            reason[strcspn(reason, "\n")] = 0;
            reason = (char*)realloc(reason, (sizeof(char) * strlen(reason)) + 1);
            pros.reasons = (char**)realloc(pros.reasons, (sizeof(char*) * prosCounter) + 1);
            strcpy(pros.reasons + prosCounter, reason);
            prosCounter += ONE;
            break;
        case TWO:
            printf("Enter a reason to add to list CON: \n");
            fgets(reason, MAX_LENGTH, stdin);
            reason[strcspn(reason, "\n")] = 0;
            reason = (char*)realloc(reason, (sizeof(char) * strlen(reason)) + 1);
            cons.reasons = (char**)realloc(cons.reasons, (sizeof(char*) * consCounter) + 1);
            strcpy(cons.reasons + consCounter, reason);
            consCounter += ONE;
            break;
        case THREE:
            printf("Your dillema: \n%s \n\n", dillema);
            printf("LIST PROS\n_________ \n");
            for (i = 0; i < prosCounter; i++)
            {
                printf("%s \n", pros.reasons + i);
            }
            printf("LIST CONS\n_________ \n");
            for (i = 0; i < consCounter; i++)
            {
                printf("%s \n", cons.reasons + i);
            }
            printf("\n\n");
            break;
        case EXIT:
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't put the output on an external site. Reduce your code to a minimal example.

Comment: Unless `ONE`, `TWO`, and `THREE` could be something different than 1, 2, and 3, those macros are only confusing. If you want to add one, 1 is not a "magic number", it's *the* number.

Comment: I see several issues here. You’re mixing up pointers and double pointers, reallocing only one byte when you need more for a pointer, reallocing strings needlessly to possibly remove one byte, use a struct which only has one variable and the counter is outside it... Also for simplicity, `sizeof char` is always 1 and return value of `malloc` shouldn’t be cast

Comment: This code would/will be *almost* legible if you (a) get rid of *all* of the unnecessary and ill-advised casts (which is *all* of them), and (b) get rid of *all* of the `sizeof(char)`, which is *always* `1` regardless of platform, and therefore completely pointless.

Answer (score 0):

These are the lines causing the problem (only the second line, but I show also the first one to show the context):

```
pros.reasons = (char**)realloc(pros.reasons, (sizeof(char*) * prosCounter) + 1);
strcpy(pros.reasons + prosCounter, reason);
```

Basically you are copying a whole string into an uninitialized pointer.

If you just want to point to the string, assign a pointer to it.  If you want a copy, you should be using `strndup()`